Check if instance/daemon is running
I want a program to tell me if it is already running, if I try to start at, while it's active.
Fx. in the terminal, I can get the status of a daemon by doing: sudo /etc/init.d/myDaemon status
But how can I get its status in the code below, where I wrote if [ daemon is already running ]?
case "$1" in
     start)
    if [ daemon is already running ]
        then
        echo "Service already running"
        else
        echo "Daemon has been started"
        fi
esac


If you’re using systemd, and chances are you are, if systemctl is-active --quiet some-service would suffice.

Also, this smells like an XY problem. Any decent init system would let you ‘start’ a service even if it is already started. What are you really trying to do?

Which system, which version... What give sudo /etc/init.d/myDaemon status as anwer and as result code? ...

What you can try to filter the output for the word "running" or execute myDaemon start to start the daemon. Otherwise, show the correct way to run the myDaemon script.
DAEMON="/etc/init.d/myDaemon"

case "$1" in
    start)
        if "$DAEMON" status | grep -q "running"; then
            echo "Service already running"
        else
            "$DAEMON" start
            echo "Daemon has been started"
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start}"
        ;;
esac

